# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) issue

Tags: php, html

I'm currently working on a PHP blog script. Here's my code:

```
<?php
include('admin/db_connect.php');
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, body FROM posts");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body);
?>

<div id="mainbox">
<?php
while($query->fetch());
?>
<h2><?php echo $title?></h2>
<p><?php echo $body?></p>
<?php endwhile?>



</div>
<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

When I visit my website however, I'm provided with the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in /home/public_html/blog.php on line 19
```

I'm unsure as to why this error is occurring, so instructions on how to resolve it would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) `while($query->fetch());` -> `while($query->fetch()):` 2) `<?php endwhile?>` -> `<?php endwhile;?>`

Comment: `<?php endwhile?>` will work too.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your answers..

Comment: @JugglingBob Give it another look: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Answer (score 2):

Instead of  `;` use  `:` Read [while()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php).

```
while($query->fetch()):
```

`;` is used in php for  terminated  each statement.

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures;
>   namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic
>   form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon
>   (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;,
>   or endswitch;, respectively.

Comment: ***Why?*** Should OP change out `;` with `:` ?